# linklist not showing nodes, please check the code

Tags: c, data-structures

This is a code for double link list which is compiling error free but it only showing the data of first node ,not traversing any other node. Can anyone help me with it please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next,*prev;
};
struct node *head,*temp,*temp1;
void main(){
    int c=1;
    clrscr();
    while(c)
    {
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("enter the data for the node\n");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        if(head==NULL){
            head=temp;
            head->next=NULL;
            head->prev=NULL;
        }
        else {
            head->next=temp;
            temp->prev=NULL;
            temp->next=NULL;
        }
        printf("for new node enter 1 otherwise 0\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);

    }
    temp1=head;
    while(temp1->next!=NULL){
        printf("%d",temp1->data);
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find the updated code:

```
while(c)
{
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("enter the data for the node\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp->data);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
        head->prev=NULL;
        temp1=head; // save head of linked list

    }
    else {
        head->next=temp;
        temp->prev=head; // make link to the previous list
        temp->next=NULL;
        head = head->next; // move head further
    }
    printf("for new node enter 1 otherwise 0\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);

}
while(temp1){ // print list while it is not null
    printf("%d",temp1->data);
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
```

Comment: but in the if case the new head is not linked with the temp how will that work??

Comment: Congrats on your first answer but code only answers are discouraged here. Don't do it. All the very best. You can first explain where it went wrong - it helps OP.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you did so. Notice these 3 lines

```
        head->next=temp;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        temp->next=NULL;
```

And what do you think you did here? `head`'s next node will be the new one and then you have set both prev + next of this newly created node to be `NULL`. (Not even using the double links correctly). And then you again insert the newly created node in same way. Think about the previously added node. Where is it now? Well there is no pointer pointing to it. And yes you lost it. This is known as [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). So all you are doing is adding one extra node with the `head` node.

So it should print the two nodes? You again did something wrong. The condition for iteration is `temp1->next != NULL` so ideally you are saying if some node points to nothing via it's member `next` you wouldn't consider it for printing. That literally eliminated the last node of that two node list from being printed.

[Here](https://ideone.com/nMG7Ei) is an illustration. Check it. Yes two things you will add to this code

- checking the return value of `malloc`.
- Freeing the nodes when you are done working with it.

Comment: understood thanks guys ,i not getting why we are moving head further head=head-> next please explain it

Comment: @abhisheksahoo.: Look, you have lots of cars and one of them is bought first. Now you want to connect every car you buy from now on using a chain. So the second car came you connected them. Then again 3rd car came - now what will you do? You will connect from 2nd to 3rd car not first to 3rd car right? That's what we did. `head = head->next` is moving to the next car so that it can link any car that comes further.

Comment: @abhisheksahoo.: Got it - clear now? Ask me if it's still not clear.